# CollectionFS crashes app on heroku - Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined

Tags: heroku, meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

I've deployed my meteor app on heroku and using [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) to upload image files to Amazon S3.
Everything had been working fine until I uploaded a few images and then had to restart the server owing to deployment.

My code for transformation:

```
transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    try {
      gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(width, height, opts.resize).interlace(opts.interlace).stream().pipe(writeStream);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(error);
    }
  }
```

But since that first restart, I've been unable to start the server back again. This is the error I've been getting.

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch.
Stopping process with SIGKILL
FS.Transform.createWriteStream transform function failed, Error:
Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 137
```

Currently, I've commented out all the collectionFS code and that has helped me get the site back up. The code works fine on local, however, heroku deployments keep failing.

Answer (score 0):

This key to your problem is this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined`.

See in your code: `gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(...)`

In other words, `gm` is undefined and you can safely assume that `graphicsmagick` isn't installed on your heroku instance.

Try using this: https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick

Comment: I looked up the build log, heroku does install this pack https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-cedar-14
But, it was already working before. It shouldn't have failed after another deploy.